# Visual Studio 2015 is renaming my function? How do I stop it?

Tags: visual-c++

I have a library that implements two classes, let's call them `A` and `B`. `A` has a function `GetMessage()` which returns a pointer to an instance of class `B`:

```
class A
{
    ...

    B *GetMessage();
};
```

The library builds fine. I use a .defs file to export the symbol.

I then have a program that instantiates `A` and calls `GetMessage()` on it. This compiles fine, but at link time I get an error like:

```
error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: class B * __thiscall A::GetMessageA(void)" ... etc. etc.
```

If I modify my project setting to use Unicode then I get an error like:

```
error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: class B * __thiscall A::GetMessageW(void)" ... etc. etc.
```

In case you can't spot the error, `GetMessage()` has been renamed to `GetMessageA()` in the first error and `GetMessageW()` in the second.

I can see what is happening. Visual Studio is completely ignoring the fact that the GetMessage function is NOT a Microsoft function and something somewhere is modifying the function name to direct the function call to the correct implementation based on my multi-char/unicode project setting. However this function does not return or process text in any way, it is not a Microsoft function that supports a dual implementation, and I have done nothing in my source code to indicate that it is.

I am NOT going to wreck my perfectly good code by renaming the function just to work around Microsoft's stupidity.

How do I stop Visual Studio from renaming my function when compiling?

----UPDATE----

The following works, but is there a project setting or something I can use instead. This code is supposed to be Posix compatible cross-platform code that is free from Microsoft inspired kludgy hacks!

```
#ifdef GetMessage
// Microsoft have a #define somewhere that redefines GetMessage() to GetMessageA() or GetMessageW()
// and then nobody can link to this library. If I ever get my hands on a functioning time machine then
// number 1 on the agenda is preventing Microsoft from ever being founded. They are constantly forcing
// me to put kludgy hacks like this into my beautiful code!
#undef GetMessage
#endif
```

Comment: `windows.h`, or some header included therefrom, defines `GetMessage` as a macro. Macros, of course, can't tell a "Microsoft function" from not a "Microsoft function" - they just blindly replace any matching text. So basically, your options are to undef the macro, or to avoid including `windows.h`.

Comment: In case it helps, this is how Google protobuf library deals with the issue: [one](https://github.com/protocolbuffers/protobuf/blob/master/src/google/protobuf/port_def.inc#L350) [two](https://github.com/protocolbuffers/protobuf/blob/master/src/google/protobuf/port_undef.inc#L69) [three](https://github.com/protocolbuffers/protobuf/blob/master/src/google/protobuf/stubs/port.h#L49)

Comment: @Igor, I know this is very late, but I fail to see the relevance of those three links to my question. I am not struggling to export the symbol, I am struggling to stop Microsoft renaming my function.

Comment: The files changed, and the links no longer point to the lines I meant them to point to. Just search for `GetMessage` in `port_def.inc` and `port_undef.inc`, and see how `port.h` includes these two.

Comment: Thanks. That looks neat. Can you make that an answer so I can accept it?